# Can I change the challenge my insight or proposal is located in?

Tags: catalyst

I have created a proposal in a challenge and realized that there is a more suitable challenge for my proposal.

When I edit the proposal, the drop-down choice for challenge is greyed-out.
How can I change the challenge my proposal is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the admins (Marek B.  @marklar) can change the challenge it is in if you ping him in telegram.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this is not possible right now. You have to recreate it and delete the other one.

:(